# Convert char array to string (including non printable characters) in C?

Tags: c, non-ascii-characters

Say I have the following:

```
static const unsigned char key[] = {
    0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77,
    0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff
};
```

How do I convert this into a string (including unprintable characters) in C?

I have searched Google and SO... but only manage to find how to convert if the characters are human-ASCII 0-9 A-Z.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A C string is just a char array that is null-terminated, so all you need to do is copy the array to a new array that has a size one larger, and set the last element in that array to `0`.